# Dynamically add shape spanning across n tableview cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've got an existing table with one class per row, grouped by week.  But the classes aren't tied to a given day - effectively it is a checklist of complete these x things in week one.

I'm now considering adding the ability to group classes within a day (still inside the week) - and my thinking is I can add an indication of which Day a given class belongs to with a coloured label.  Easy to do if I'm willing to repeat the same labels (e.g., Day 3 would show twice, once per row, in this example).  Ideally, I'd instead span all rows for a given day with one label, that has the text centred across the n classes in that Day - in line with the design below.

However, this is where I'm stuck because I now have an element that spans across tableview rows and I'm not sure where to start with this one.  I'd like to avoid going down the path of nested tableviews where each Day becomes a tableview within the overall tableview...but worried that may be the best path forward.

I could potentially fake it by adding one label per row, and just hiding the text if it is row >1 of that day (though would miss the centring desire)...

[image: Image of rows with labels]

Comment: You cannot have one view span two rows. But you can in theory have one view per row which, together, _look_ like your drawing.

Comment: So, I can make that work if I have an odd number of elements - because I could show the label in the middle row, appearing centred. But I’m not sure how I’d make it work splitting the text in half and get the spacing right. Thoughts?

Comment: If you have two rows and one shows half of the label and the other shows the other half of another label, it looks like one label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is particularly daunting. Here's a proof-of-concept example I threw together in a couple of minutes:

[image]

That's a table view with two rows; the first row's background color is green and the second row's background color is red, so you can clearly distinguish them.

There appears to be a yellow label overlapping both rows. But in fact there are *two* labels, one in each row. The first row displays the right half of its label; the other half just goes off into empty space and is clipped. The second row displays the left half of *its* label; the other half goes off into empty space and is clipped. But together they look like one label.

Here's the relevant part of `cellForRow`:

```
    let lab = UILabel(frame: CGRect(
                        x: 0, y: 0,
                        width: tableView.rowHeight * 2, height: 30))
    lab.backgroundColor = .yellow
    lab.text = "Hello"
    lab.textAlignment = .center
    lab.center = CGPoint(
        x:lab.bounds.height / 2,
        y: indexPath.row == 0 ? tableView.rowHeight : 0)
    lab.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -.pi/2)
```

Clearly you could do that sort of calculation for any number of rows to be clumped together in this way.

Comment: amazing - thanks Matt - exactly what I'm looking for